# Overflow Error in numpy exp function on iPython

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit an exponential curve to some data (nuclear decay data) using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. (This is on data hub server on an `iPython` notebook)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

N,t = np.loadtxt('Ba137.txt', unpack=True) #original data points

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,N,'r.')

def regression_func(t, n_0, L):  #exponential curve fitting function
    return n_0*np.exp(-L*t)    
parameters = curve_fit(regression_func, t, N)[0]

N_0, Lambda = parameters

x=np.linspace(0,500,1000)     #plotting the 'fitted' curve
y=N_0*np.exp(-Lambda*x)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

However, when I run this I get the following errors:

```
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:11:  RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
```

and

```
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:779: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
 category=OptimizeWarning)
```

The curve also does not fit anywhere near the original data points:
[First Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WijzF.png)

After playing around for a bit, the curve acquired a very close fit when I divided L by some small number greater than 1 (I used 1.094) in regression_function (but not Lambda in the final plot function). Any value smaller than 1.094 (assuming 3 d.p) would cause the curve to revert to a straight line and as this 'normalisation' value became larger the fit of the curve became worse. When dividing L by 1.094, the covariance warning would disappear but the runtime warning prevails.
[After dividing L by 1.094](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHSlV.png)

Why is this happening? How can I attain accurate regression parameters without this arbitrary division?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the initial parameter estimates, which for curve_fit are all 1.0 by default unless you supply them. Here is example code using your equation (plus an offset you may not need) and scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to give initial parameter estimates. This scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, and that algorithm requires parameter bounds within which to search - in this example, these bounds are taken from the max and min data values, but if you might choose different search bounds.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(t, n_0, L, offset): #exponential curve fitting function
    return n_0*numpy.exp(-L*t) + offset


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # seach bounds for n_0
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # seach bounds for L
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY]) # seach bounds for Offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)

print('Parameters', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```